# Strong Dependence

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, it.information-theory, st.statistics

I asked [this question on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/181840/strong-dependence), but no answer.

I don't know if this definition has been already given.

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are two random variables over finite alphabets $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{Y}$. We say $Y$ is *strongly dependent* on $X$ if for *any* real-valued non-degenerate function acting on $\mathcal{Y}$, $f(Y)$ is also dependent on $X$.

Here I need to assume that $f(Y)$ is non-degenerate because if $f$ is a constant function then $f(Y)$ in independent of both $X$ and $Y$.

What can we know about $P_{XY}$ if $Y$ is strongly dependent on $X$?

Any necessary and sufficient condition for $Y$ being strongly dependent on $X$?

Comment: By "dependent" do you just mean "not independent"?

Comment: Link to MO question?

Comment: @SashoNikolov, yes by "dependent" I mean "not independent".